# Why do I have favicon.ico error in my GAE dashboard?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml, favicon

I have the following in my app.yaml (python is used):

```
handlers:
- url: /ico/
  static_dir: templates/ico
```

So, *favicon.ico* is located as *templates\ico\favicon.ico*. HTML files (also located at *templates* folder, but used as templates from the main app) refer to this file as

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.ico">
```

or

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ico/favicon.ico">
```

(depends on final URL)

And favicon is displayed.
Should I define it [additionally](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#erroruris) as

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: templates/ico/favicon.ico
  upload: templates/ico/favicon\.ico
```

What is the reason, if so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should define it additionally as you mention (as a handler at the root level). My understanding is that the favicon is traditionally served from the root directory of a site in general (even outside of App Engine), and therefore the path `/favicon.ico` will be called by the browser when loading the site (I'm not an expert, so take this with a grain of salt). Therefore in order to prevent that error, you must provide a handler for that specific path that serves your favicon.

Comment: You can even see this behavior by going to most sites and adding the favicon.ico path to them like http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico